# Generated IPA disributed over TestFlightApp.com looks different than Simulator and iOS Device

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have a project that looks awesome on the Simulator and on iOS device if I build and Run with Xcode, but if I achieve the project and upload to TestFlighApp, when I download the app on the same iPad I tested the project previously, it looks different.

Does anybody knows why this happens? I have no clue on how to debug this.

Please refer to the following sample, both screenshots taken from the device, one using the IPA and other running from Xcode on iOS device.

[image]

Those black lines.. I don't know where they come from

Comment: Can you describe the difference ?

Comment: I added a screenshot, most UIViews gain that strange black line at the top. Only on IPA version

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be in `Compress PNG Files` option in your project `Build settings`.

Also check that build configurations of XCode scheme for `Run` and `Archive` are the same (must be `Release`).